# Handling multi logins

Tags: javascript, node.js

my web application doesn't handle multi user logins if i logged in to the web with my account then I opened a new tab to enter with different account it doesn't give me the log in page. how to handle this part in node ?

Comment: Most applications won't allow different users in different tabs.  If you're trying to do this for testing, the usual approach would be to run different browsers, or use private browsing for one of the sessions etc.

Comment: I tested through different browsers but gave me the same problem